# Resolution error (after update?) on Yoga 2 11 16.04.3 GNOME

Tags: 16.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

so I recently started my computer (probably after a round of `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`commands and a reboot-- I use apt-get to upgrade irregularly so I'm not sure if I updated last night), and I have two displays. The second display, my 1920x1080p television, does not display in the correct resolution anymore, after this (update?). I have to scale it down to 1366x768 or my dashtodock, and my top GNOME bar on my secondary screen will be cut off from my view. Seeing as how I mainly use my TV for media and game consumption, this really irks me. I don't want to have to wait for another update to watch/play things on my TV at a decent resolution, and there is NO WAY I'm booting into my Windows harddisk. I was wondering if, with my limited knowledge of this issue, and my gnome extensions, there was an easy fix.

P.S. I've rebooted once, didn't help a thing.

Comment: Well, if the correct native resolution for the TV is set and yet the desktop bleeds out, that's something you can and should adjust in the TV itself. Probably nothing to do with updates but with what was inadvertently changed in the TV. A Yoga 2 has Intel Graphics which typically don't have issues and are not even updated, typically, in stable release (LTS).

Comment: Nothing to do with my tv, I'll reboot to Winderp and let you know but I'm 100% sure it isn't my tv

Comment: You were  right, thanks!! Idk how tf to change my tv settings and how they got changed to begin with but tyvm

Comment: Those settings vary a lot. Different manufacturers use different terminology and different "workflow". Some have a menu for that, others have a sub-menu or a sub-sub-menu... The setting name can be "Full", "PC", "Game" (or even "Game Console), etc. And there's also the odd case where it's just a key on the remote and the feature is barely documented, if at all (Toshiba).

Comment: Hahaha sorta like my Emerson TV, thank god I still have the remote.